# Where is located the temporary folder when we upload a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing Ruby-on-Rails application that stores records in a db table (number of records is not more than 200 rows). Each record is associated with an jpeg/png image or icon (max size 32x32). So my app has to upload and save the images on the server in a specific folder.

In the documentation it says "The object in the params hash is an instance of a subclass of IO. Depending on the size of the uploaded file it may in fact be a StringIO or an instance of File backed by a temporary file.".

My question: where is this temporary folder located on the server? Is it system dependent or application dependent?

Comment: Just curious, and if it is application dependent then how to configure where they should be stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location of your tempfile is probably system dependent, likely in the `/tmp` folder somewhere.

But you dont really need to know.

The uploaded image is either in memory as a StringIO object, or saved to a temporary file on the host server. This is an optimization provided by rails. If the image is small enough, Rails will pass you a StringIO object, which is basically the entire image loaded in memory. If the image is larger, it will pass you an instance that represents a temporary file on disk.

You want to just save it to a known folder, say `uploads`. You do not need to care if the image is stored in memory or stored on disk.

Both StringIO objects and temp file backed objects respond to the `:read` method. All you have to do is call read to get the data and then write it out to the location you want.

```
image_as_io = params[:image]
filename = ... # determine a filename for the image

File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', filename), 'wb') do |file|
  file.write(image_as_io.read)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I know that I don't need to know the location of the temporary files in order to store an uploaded file. I just wanted to know what is going on behind the scene when a file is uploaded.

Comment: I would assume its an instance of `Tempfile`, so it would have a `path` method you could check if you really wanted to know.

Comment: Good idea! I'll check.

Comment: Yes it works, I am using Ubuntu, and it displayed `/tmp` as expected.